# Dynamic archive names using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'd like to create multiple zip folders based on directories in the `slides` folder.

Is it possible to have the zip file names correspond to the source folders? I imagine the archive name needs to be dynamic, but I have not found anything that would suit this need.

Current directory structure.

```
/
|
gruntFile.js
package.json
build/
slides/
      |
      |---slide1/slide1.txt
      |---slide2/slide2.txt
```

Desired output.

```
/
|
gruntFile.js
package.json
build/
     |
     |---slide1.zip
     |---slide2.zip
slides/
      |
      |---slide1/slide1.txt
      |---slide2/slide2.txt
```

gruntFile.js

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    clean: {
      archive: {
        src: [ 'build' ]
      }
    },
    compress: {
      main: {
        options: {
        archive: 'build/archive.zip'
    },
    files: [
        {src: ['slides/**'], dest: '', filter: 'isFile'}
        ]
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

   grunt.registerTask(
    'default', 
    'Clean the build directory and archive all files in the slides folder', 
     [ 'clean', 'compress' ]
  );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. You can get each file in your directory by `path/**/*.txt`. The first two stars `path/**/` tells Grunt to look through every subdirectory and `*.txt` for each file.

```
compress: {
   main: {
      options: {
         mode: 'zip'
      },
      files: [{
         src: 'slides/**/*.txt',
         dest: 'build/',
         filter: 'isFile'
      }]
   }
}
```

Comment: I get 'Unable to compress; no valid archive file was specified.'. I received this error before, that's why I had to specify an archive name. Problem being, I do not want a single archive. Any suggestions?